# Old 6-piece wooden cross puzzle

Tags: geometry, mechanical-puzzles, burr-puzzle

I found this old puzzle and have no idea how to get it together. I have been trying to complete it for several hours now but to no avail. The pieces of the puzzle are as follows:

[image: Piece 1][image: Piece 2][image: Piece 3][image: Piece 4][image: Piece 5][image: Piece 6]

Also sorry if it has incorrect tag, correct me if needed, I couldn’t find any appropriate.

Comment: Do you know what it's supposed to look like when assembled?

Comment: @F1Krazy it is supposed to be a 3D plus sign.

Comment: Are the dark brown things a fixed part of the pieces? Because they look like they give away a bit of a hint.

Comment: @ilkkachu no, they are glued on solid...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Pieces 1 to 6]
**The pieces from 1 to 6 as shown in the question.**

---

*Put together the pieces* **P2** *and* **P6**
[image]

---

*Add piece* **P5**
[image]

---

*Next is piece* **P4**
[image]

---

*Next is piece* **P3**
[image]

---

*Now you have to do some moves. At first the pieces* **P3 + P6**[image]
*Now move piece* **P5**
[image]
*and piece* **P4**

*Now you can add the last piece* **P1**
[image]

---

*To move* **P1, P4, P5** *and* **P6** *gets you to the solution.*
[image]

Comment: I wish I could upvote twice, perfect answer

Comment: man thank you! I will try this tommorow, I don't have the puzzle with me now. But that looks amazing! Is there like some program for modelling those thing or is it just some 3D modelling CAD thing?

Comment: This is pretty much the same answer as I gave, just a slight variation in the order in which you assemble the pieces.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a **6-Pieces Burr Puzzle**.

[image]

If you want to get the solution:

> Visit this link: http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/devilsknot.htm
>
>  Hope one of them will fit your puzzle!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. None of the solutions in the link provided, however, wasn’t for my puzzle... But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I don't own the same puzzle as you, but I have a Burr puzzle set that is close. I am not completely sure if the solution I describe here will work on your puzzle.

I'll number the pieces #1 to #6 in the order you showed them in your question.

Combine pieces #4 and #6 to make rectangular ring. One end of the ring opening has a notch. Insert #5 into that ring so that it enters that notch.

[image]

Place #2 on one side of the ring, perpendicular to all the other pieces.

[image]

Piece #3 goes on the other side of the ring, to pair up with #2.

(Note, in the picture my thumb covers the piece a bit because I don't actually have a piece that matches your #3.)

[image]

The last piece, #1, cannot be put in place directly. The other pieces need to be slid about a bit to allow it to be inserted.

First slide #6 lengthwise, which disengages the notch from #5.

[image]

Now slide #5 up. This then allows #4 to move lengthways in the opposite direction that #6 went.

[image]

Pieces #4 and #6 have slid far enough apart that their ring is broken. This gives enough room to insert #1 inside the ring. Lastly, slide pieces #6, #5 and #4 back, and the puzzle should be solved (if I am visualising this correctly).